# Unknown Database on Mysqli Connect... However it Does Exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an error 1049 on my Mysql connect file, however I have verified this table exists.  And when I attempt to connect to it via PDO it works perfectly fine.  So obviously there's an error in my code I'm missing.

My code:

```
<?php

  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mysqliphp');

  if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Houston, we have a problem!');
  } else {
    Echo 'Everything is fine.';
  }

?>
```

The error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'mysqliphp' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\mysqliconnect.php on line 3
Houston, we have a problem!
```

What is the issue?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code snippet is absolutely fine. Except you missed password or db name .

Comment: there is no problem in your code and mysqliphp does not exist.

Comment: @MajidAbbasi it very much exists.  Perhaps I'm missing some kind of intricacy.  I'll post a picture to show it.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned table does exists that is `mysqliphp` but here you are passing that name as a database. hence the error

Comment: @Saurabh  You got it.  I realized how much of an idiot I am.  The issue was me confusing a DB with a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you have mentioned table does exists that is `mysqliphp` but here you are passing that name as a database. hence the error